# Corona SDK - Calculate position of ball with line rotation

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I got simple question, but very difficult and bad solution, I need your help.
I simply want myCircle in myLine x,y, but with change of rotation, It's bad, so..

My objects :

```
My "obj" is working well..

myLine = display.newRect( obj.x, obj.y , 150, 5 )
myCircle = display.newCircle( myLine.x, myLine.y, 8 )
```

I got for every enterFrame this :

```
myLine.x = obj.x
myLine.y = obj.y
myLine.rotation = obj.rotation

myCircle.x = myLine.x
myCircle.y = myLine.y
```

And It's working fine.. but, I need to do, myCircle for runtime - enterFrame, with every change of line rotation will be moving in same direction. It's working fine, if myCircle is
in obj.x and obj.y.. or myLine.x and myLine.y.
But I need, that myCirle would be like on the 1 end of the myLine.. 
Something like this, but better :

```
if rotation == 0 then
   myCircle.x = myLine.x
   myCircle.y = myLine.y - 30
elseif rotation == 90 then
   myCircle.x = myLine.x + 30
   myCircle.y = myLine.y
end
..
```

And so on, I think you get the idea.

All i need is to get this :

```
  *
 /
/

*
|
|
```

..

Thx for any help.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do. Please reword your request, maybe adding some details. If your English is not good enough, you can try adding a couple of images showing what you want to achieve and what you are getting instead.

Answer (score 0):

what I think you are trying to do is rotate a line, but have the circle stay at the end of the line. If that is what you are trying to do, then math.sin() and math.cos() are what you need.

```
myCircle.x = myLine.x + 30 * math.cos(rotation) --30 would be the length of the line.
myCircle.y = myLine.y + 30 * math.sin(rotation)
```

that should work, but if it doesn't, try using cos for y and sin for x instead.